# phpBB equivalent for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-forums

I'm looking for Forum software similar to phpBB, but intended to run within a RoR application.  I'm looking for a list of sites, along with one recommendation for which one is currently the ideal choice (ease of setup, simplicity, aesthetics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[RForum](http://rforum.andreas-s.net/)? Used by [ruby-forum.com](http://www.ruby-forum.com/).

e: There's also [Beast](http://beast.caboo.se/), but it looks very minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [rBoard](https://github.com/radar/rboard/tree), its on github.